# Instagram API returns only 4 likes data

Tags: instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram API to fetch images with a certain hashtag that have been liked by my organization. But when the API makes the get call, the response comes back with data like this, where the like count is 83 (!) and the actual like data returned only shows 4 (!). I've seen postings here that indicate that Instagram returns about 120 data for likes. How come I'm only getting four?

The api call I'm using is:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag/media/recent/?client_id=myclientID

```
"likes": {
                "count": 83,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "username": "something",
                        "profile_picture": "picture",
                        "id": "idhere",
                        "full_name": "namehere"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "",
                        "profile_picture": "",
                        "id": "",
                        "full_name": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "",
                        "profile_picture": "",
                        "id": "",
                        "full_name": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "",
                        "profile_picture": "",
                        "id": "",
                        "full_name": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: For now, I'm just using a workaround of NOT relying on which pictures we liked. Instead, we're reposting the pictures we like, then I'm using the username to show the photos we reposted. Sigh. It's not what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch medias from Instagram using these endpoints:

`/users/<user-id>/media/recent`

`/tags/<tag-name>/media/recent`

You wouldn't have all likes in the response; same for comments. **It's just limit set by Instagram**. I think it might be really expensive to return all (or a lot) likes/comments in each media users fetch.

But don't worry, If you get medias you want, you will have their `id` and you could use this endpoint:

`/media/<media-id>/likes`

And then you will have all likes  (use pagination to *fetch them all*) and do a great stuff with them.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: /media/{media-id}/likes does not have pagination, but if you check it regularly you should hopefully be able to see all likes as they come through.

Answer (score 0):

This could be three things:

1) A bug, but that's unlikely (ha a pun!)

2) Pagination.  You need to ask for more data in another call with [MIN_TAG_ID and/or MAX_TAG_ID set](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent).

3) Privacy.  Instagram users have privacy settings on their profiles.  Described [here](https://help.instagram.com/281388201973414).  This would definitely lower the count even with pagination.

Comment: Thanks. It isn't a private account. I'll look at min_tag_id and max_tag_id.

Comment: You need to ask for more data in another call with MIN_TAG_ID and/or MAX_TAG_ID set. - how would I do that?

Comment: Hey @LauraNMS, well for starters read the documentation in the link.  Then add the parameter to the request.  This is pretty basic stuff, but that's ok, it's where we all started.  Check out this tutorial on HTTP: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177  tutsplus.com is a great site.  You might consider a subscription.

Comment: Re: the private account.  I think *other* accounts on instagram may be private to *your* account.  So your account may know there are 83 likes, but not be able to request them.